# What's wrong with the OutputStreamWriter used to write in socket for server?

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am trying to learn socket programming. I wrote client using `InputStreamReader` and with `BufferedReader` I read the msg sent from server.
For server if I write `PrintWriter` with `print` method it works and with `write` method it's not, why?
And `OutputStreamReader` is not at all useful as it does not have `print` method and with `write`, I am not getting messages in client side.

Client:

```
Socket c=new Socket("143.22.165.27",6000);
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String s=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
```

Server

```
Socket sock=s.accept();
             OutputStreamWriter out =
                     new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                 out.write("...........");
```

Comment: You could show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using the `readLine()` method on the client's `BufferedReader`. So my guess would be that you aren't writing any newline characters when you use the `write()` methods on the server. Thus, the client never reaches the end of a line. A `PrintStream` or a `PrintWriter` adds the newline characters for you whenever you call a `println()` method.

Of course, without any code or even a description of the problem, it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You must use out.flush() every time when you want to sent portion of data via out.write(msg).